# how to find the last Image of Gallery in android

Tags: android, gallery

I am working on Gallery View in android. I am sliding the Images in Gallery View , I need to check the last Image of the Gallery images. After reaching at the end of the Gallery Images if user swipe more than I have to move to another activity . I am confused about how to detect the End of the Gallery Images.

```
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
    img.setImageResource(CopyRightPagesActivity.typedImgsCopyRight.getResourceId(index, 1));
    img.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information.

Comment: @Amit what else you need more for knowledge. i think i have don it.